# How do I make a Quartz job wait for another task that is fired by ApplicationListener?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

So, I have a Quartz job, and an ApplicationListener that gets fired when the Quartz job is done. My problem is that any finalization that I do in the listener will create a race condition for the code that polls to check if the Quartz job is done. Basically I want either make the Quartz job wait for the ApplicationListener to start and finish before considering itself done.

Is this even possible? Am I mixing frameworks?

Comment: Please post some code. I am unable to get you. May be in your onExecution(){ publisher.publish() something like this}

Comment: Left for the weekend, may be able to post sample code tomorrow :(

Comment: Quartz is for simple scheduling. What you want is available as part of spring batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was lack of familiarity with the code base. Everything was wired correctly, but I used the wrong JobKey to search for listeners before allowing the main job to shut down. Sorry to waste your time guys.